# server side rendering angular

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I need to create a server side rendering angular project with ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
https://github.com/enten/angular-universal
i have cloned the above repo and added my code in it
to run it I need to use "ng serve" command
how can I check if server side rending is working properly since to run ssr project the comand is npm en dev:ssr
could anyone confirm if ssr is happening

I tried to check server side rendering is happening or not by using
if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
console.log("Server");
and it does print server in console[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGQD5.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: In the webbrowser you can just right-click -> View source and then check if the html of the page you visit is there, or if it's just the index.html you're seeing